# IF Statement in Excel using multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to make an IF statement that adds 1 for every set of cells that matches a certain criteria:

```
=SUM(IF(AND(Sheet1!A1=B2, Sheet1!C2=B3),1,0))
```

However, whenever I make a new sheet I want the B2 and B3 of that sheet to be included in the relationship. Is there a way to do this while also not including B2 or B3 in Sheet1?

Comment: You want the formula to automatically update itself, when you add a new sheet? I'm assuming, say, `Sheet2` is the ActiveSheet. And you're going to add `Sheet3` and you want the formula to update automatically to be: `=SUM(IF(AND(Sheet1!A1=B2=Sheet2!B2, Sheet1!C2=B3=Sheet2!B3),1,0))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function. Open **VBA Editor**, Insert module and paste below mentioned code.

```
Function FINDMATCH() As Long
    Dim Sheet1, sht As Worksheet
    Dim counter As Long
    Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    counter = 0
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = sht.Range("B2").Value And Sheet1.Range("C2").Value = sht.Range("B3").Value Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    FINDMATCH = counter
End Function
```

Add values to be checked at A1 and C2 of Sheet1 and at B2 & B3 in every other sheet.

Write `function =FINDMATCH()` in any cell and you will get the result.